# SageMaker GetBucketLocation operation: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, access-denied, amazon-sagemaker

I have a SM notebook in Oregon region and I've ran estimator.fit with data in a S3 bucket of the same region several times previously. Today on attempting to rerun this script I'm getting the following error:

```
INFO:sagemaker:Creating training-job with name: sagemaker-tensorflow-scriptmode-2019-01-31-18-51-07-292
Creating tmp_axa2vmo_algo-1-s8vfu_1 ... 
Attaching to tmp_axa2vmo_algo-1-s8vfu_1
algo-1-s8vfu_1  | 2019-01-31 18:51:11,828 sagemaker-containers INFO     Imported framework sagemaker_tensorflow_container.training
algo-1-s8vfu_1  | 2019-01-31 18:51:11,940 sagemaker-containers ERROR    Reporting training FAILURE
algo-1-s8vfu_1  | 2019-01-31 18:51:11,940 sagemaker-containers ERROR    framework error: 
algo-1-s8vfu_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
algo-1-s8vfu_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sagemaker_containers/_trainer.py", line 67, in train
algo-1-s8vfu_1  |     entrypoint()
algo-1-s8vfu_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sagemaker_tensorflow_container/training.py", line 167, in main
algo-1-s8vfu_1  |     s3_utils.configure(env.hyperparameters.get('model_dir'), os.environ.get('SAGEMAKER_REGION'))
algo-1-s8vfu_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sagemaker_tensorflow_container/s3_utils.py", line 23, in configure
algo-1-s8vfu_1  |     os.environ['S3_REGION'] = _s3_region(job_region, model_dir)
algo-1-s8vfu_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sagemaker_tensorflow_container/s3_utils.py", line 39, in _s3_region
algo-1-s8vfu_1  |     bucket_location = s3.get_bucket_location(Bucket=bucket_name)['LocationConstraint']
algo-1-s8vfu_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
algo-1-s8vfu_1  |     return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
algo-1-s8vfu_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
algo-1-s8vfu_1  |     raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
algo-1-s8vfu_1  | botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetBucketLocation operation: Access Denied
algo-1-s8vfu_1  | 
algo-1-s8vfu_1  | An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetBucketLocation operation: Access Denied
tmp_axa2vmo_algo-1-s8vfu_1 exited with code 1
Aborting on container exit...
```

To my knowledge no role permissions or access policies have been updated. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: I also experience this occasionally. The only workaround I found so far is restarting the notebook instance

Comment: Hi Austin, Could you check if the role used to create SageMaker Notebook Instance has permission to access '*sagemaker*' s3 buckets ?